# Getting all of these text using BeautifulSoup, select

Tags: select, beautifulsoup

I'm writting script to extract all of texts in attached picture by using select method.
But so far, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMy6W.jpg)only last text "再生医療・美容点滴" can be extract.

I thought "select" is a way to extract every appropirate css selector.

Is there somebody why?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

links =[
 "https://report.clinic/detail/L_3020779"
]

for link in links:
  r = requests.get(link)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
  data1 = list()
  
  data_url = ""

  for urls in soup.select(".menu_side_item .list_common .list_item_link .display_flex"):
        #links = urls.get("href")
        links = urls.get_text().strip()
        data_url = links


  data1.append(data_url)

print(data_url)
```

```
**text I want extract**:
目・二重整形
鼻の整形
しわ・たるみ整形(注入、糸、フェイスリフト)
輪郭・顎・エラ・額・小顔整形
口元・唇の整形・人中短縮
豊胸・胸の整形
脂肪吸引
婦人科形成

タトゥー除去
目元・クマ・眉下・涙袋整形
乳首・乳輪の整形

医療脱毛
ニキビ・ニキビ跡の治療
HIFU・照射系リフトアップ治療
シミ取り・肝斑・毛穴治療
わきが手術・多汗症治療
薄毛治療
痩身、メディカルダイエット
再生医療・美容点滴
```

[text I want extract 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMy6W.jpg)
[text I want extract 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oje1k.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is `indentation` - Depending on your expected behavior move `data1` before your loops, `data1.append(data_url)` and `print(data_url)` into your second loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

links =[
 "https://report.clinic/detail/L_3020779"
]
data1 = list()
for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

    for urls in soup.select(".menu_side_item .list_common .list_item_link .display_flex"):
        links = urls.get_text().strip()
        data_url = links
        data1.append(data_url)
        print(data_url)
```